# Using AFOAuth1Client with different server endpoint addresses

Tags: ios, oauth

I am attempting to authenticate an API that has 3 different server end points:

- [Request token URL](http://api.XXX.com/oauth/request_token)
- [Authorize URL](http://www.XXX.com/oauth/authorize)
- [Access token URL](http://api.XXX.com/oauth/access_token)

The issue arises when AFOAuth1Client requires an initialization with a baseURL.  I have tried @"", nil and @"http://", these all trigger crashes in the AFOAuth1Client initialization.

My question is: how can I create an instance of AFOAuth1Client that either has a baseURL of nil or how can I change the parameters of the `authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath` to allow me to use the correct paths?  (Authorize URL has www. whereas Request URL and Access URL do not have www.).

```
   AFOAuth1Client *client = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]key:kConsumerKey secret:kConsumerSecret];
   [client authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:@"http://api.XXX.com/oauth/request_token" userAuthorizationPath:@"http://www.XXX.com/oauth/authorize" callbackURL:nil accessTokenPath:@"http://api.XXX.com/oauth/access_token" accessMethod:@"Identity"   
       success:^(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken) {
           NSLog(@"successful login");
     } failure:^(NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"could not login error %@", error);
     }];
```

Comment: Links provided in your question are faulty

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to edit the AFHTTPClient interface file.

Change the @property baseUrl to:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, retain) NSURL *baseURL;
```

This allows us to make the baseURL dynamic based on the current address being entered.  In my case AuthorizeURL/ Request Token/ Access Token.

Next I updated the AFOAuth1Client class and manually changed the baseURL by updating the following method with the correct baseURL:

```
 (void)authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:(NSString *)requestTokenPath
                      userAuthorizationPath:(NSString *)userAuthorizationPath
                                callbackURL:(NSURL *)callbackURL
                            accessTokenPath:(NSString *)accessTokenPath
                               accessMethod:(NSString *)accessMethod
                                    success:(void (^)(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken))success 
                                    failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
```

...

```
    //set baseURL
    self.baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.XXX.com/"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:userAuthorizationPath parameters:parameters] URL]];

    //reset it back
    self.baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.XXX.com/"];
```

Comment: AFOAuth1Client is NOT self-contained, it relies on AFNetworking and you need populate all these changes into AFNetworking stack. It is not as simple as first glance.